# Writing to Firebase with Ruby

Tags: ruby, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a simple script to write data to a google Firebase account. I have installed the Firebase library through gem and haven't experienced errors related to it, so I don't think it is my issue.

My Firebase is named venice-testing, so at the start of the script I do

```
firebase_uri = 'https://venice-testing.firebaseio.com/'
@firebase = Firebase::Client.new(firebase_uri)
```

After obtaining data, I use

```
response = @firebase.push("favorite_breweries", {
    :name => @hash[search_term.to_i].to_s,})
```

To attempt to write do the firebase account

Maybe I just don't understand enough about this subject, but any descriptions I have found thus far on how to write data to firebase have not worked for me.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Don't provide a link to your code. Include the [minimal code needed to reproduce the problem in the question itself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not you meant to share your brewery API key with the internet, so I removed the pastebin link to be safe. But please show the error - saying "its not working" isn't always enough to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the 'secret key'

try this:

```
firebase_url    = 'https://youfirebase.firebaseio.com/'
firebase_secret = '123SecReTKey321'
firebase = Firebase::Client.new(firebase_url, firebase_secret)
response = firebase.push("clients", { :name => 'silvio', :subname => 'santos' })
p response
```